# Webpack: NormalModuleReplacementPlugin -> TS Parser Error: "Cannot find module... '", but built bundle is working

Tags: webpack, alias

I am new to Webpack and a bit confused about some features of it. I have uploaded my [testproject](https://github.com/kamekazemaster/webpack-test) to GitHub where I test some functionalities of Webpack.

### What I want to achieve

I want to dynamically replace certain placeholders in requests of require/import statements. As far as I found out this feature should be built in to Webpack with the plugin `NormalModuleReplacementPlugin`.

### What is the problem?

The bundle is built from Webpack and I am able to run the web app. I can reach the server and the bundle apparently is functioning. But I am getting parser Errors from TS(?). When using the plugin `NormalModuleReplacementPlugin` there appear parser errors which do NOT influence the functionality of the produced bundle. I am still able to load the bundle and everything is fine. (This happens when replacing the placeholder `$platform` (or any other) with the replacement `hyperion` in the file `a/b/c/test3.ts` in the import statement from `foo1/t/z/lil.platform.test.$platform`)

The error is:

```
ERROR in ./a/b/c/test3.ts
(2,22): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'foo1/t/z/lil.platform.test.$platform'.
```

### What I have tried so far

I have no idea why replacing placeholder through the `NormalModuleReplacementPlugin` leads to parse Errors. I tried to locate the alias resolving in the source code of webpack in order to investigate how the aliases are resolved, but I was not able to find the lines in the source code. I then tried to write my own plugin hooking into "normal-module-factory" and "before/after-resolve" resulting in the same situation. (my own plugin is also located in the `webpack.config.js`). Here I investigated the "result" object passed to the function of the "before/after-resolve" hooks. I tried to also overwrite `result.dependency.userRequest` and `result.dependency.request` as well as `result.userRequest` in the "before-resolve" hook.

PS: Feedback and or hints for the webpack.config.js would be nice too ;)

For simplicity I also post the `webpack.config.js` here:

```
var path = require("path");
var webpack = require("webpack");
var $ld = require("lodash");
var fs = require("fs");


function DynamicPathReplacementPlugin(placeholder, replacement) {
  var _ = require('lodash');

  if (!placeholder) {
    throw new Error('Webpack DynamicPathReplacementPlugin: argument "placeholder" must be defined!')
  }
  if (!replacement) {
    throw new Error('Webpack DynamicPathReplacementPlugin: argument "replacement" must be defined!')
  }
  if (!_.isRegExp(placeholder) && !_.isString(placeholder)) {
    throw new Error('Webpack DynamicPathReplacementPlugin: argument "placeholder" must be either a RegExp or a String!')
  }
  if (!_.isFunction(replacement) && !_.isString(replacement)) {
    throw new Error('Webpack DynamicPathReplacementPlugin: argument "replacement" must be either a Function or a String!')
  }

  return {
    'apply':  function(compiler) {
      compiler.plugin(
        'normal-module-factory',

        function(normalModuleFactory) {
          normalModuleFactory.plugin(
            'before-resolve',

            function (result, callback) {
              if(!result) return callback();
              if (_.isFunction(replacement)) {
                replacement = _.bind(replacement, {}, placeholder);
              }
              result.request = _.replace(result.request, placeholder, replacement);

              return callback(null, result);
            }
          );
          normalModuleFactory.plugin(
            'after-resolve',

            function (result, callback) {

              if(!result) return callback();
              if (_.isFunction(replacement)) {
                replacement = _.bind(replacement, {}, placeholder);
              }
              // result.resource = path.resolve(path.dirname(result.resource), _.replace(result.resource, placeholder, replacement));
              if (result.request.includes("lil")){
                console.log(result)
                // console.log(path.basename(_.replace(result.resource, placeholder, replacement)))
                // result.resource = path.basename(_.replace(result.request, placeholder, replacement));
                // result.request = _.replace(result.resource, placeholder, replacement);
                // result.userRequest = _.replace(result.request, placeholder, replacement);
              }
              return callback(null, result);
            }
          );
        }
      );

      // compiler.plugin("after-resolvers", function(compiler) {
      //   console.log("after-resolvers", compiler.resolvers.normal.apply)
      // });
    }
  };
}


module.exports = {
  debug: true,
  entry: "./entry.js",
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  target: 'web',
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {test: /\.less$/, loaders: ['style', 'css', 'less']},
      {test: /\.css$/, loaders: ['style', 'css']},
      {test: /\.(png|jpg)$/, loader: 'file'},
      {test: /\.html$/, loader: 'html'},
      {test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json'},
      {test: /\.ts$/, loaders: ['ts']},
      {test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel', query: {presets: ['es2015', 'react']}},
    ]
  },
  resolve : {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts', '.json'],
    root: [
      path.resolve(__dirname),
      //path.resolve('./src'), // Beispiele für die Anwendung von globalen Pfaden
      //path.resolve('./src/q/w'),
      ],
    alias: {
      foo: "a/b",
      bar: "a/b/c/bar/src",
      bar1: "a/b/c/bar1/src",
      foo1: "src/q/w/e/r",
      baz: "src/q"
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    // DynamicPathReplacementPlugin(/\$platform/, function(a) {
    //   console.log("exec3", a);
    //   return "hyperion"
    // }),
    new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(/\$platform/, function(result) {
      console.log("exec");
      var temp = $ld.replace(result.request, /\$platform/gi, "hyperion");
      // $ld.set(result, 'dependency.userRequest', temp);
      // $ld.set(result, 'dependency.request', temp);
      result.request = temp;
    })
  ]
};
```

Comment: I have a similar problem with NormalModuleReplacementPlugin that eslint-import-resolver-webpack is not able to find the file.